# Pointer to a function that accepts both const and non-const arguments

Tags: c, unix, pointers

I want to write a wrapper for read and write unix functions, but read has a const void pointer parameter, and write a simple void pointer as a parameter.

So, a prototype like this, will fail for one of the functions:

```
typedef ssize_t (*genericStreamHandler)(int, const void*, size);
```

Comment: Why do you use `const` then?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @cad: Is it? I get: `passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]` from gcc, with `foo`being `void foo(void*);` getting passed in a `const char *`.

Comment: error: invalid conversion from     'ssize_t (*)(int, const void*, size_t) {aka long int (*)(int, const void*, long unsigned int)}' to 'streamHandler {aka long int (*)(int, void*, long unsigned int)}' [-fpermissive]
         streamHandler(write, gClientFD, (void *)&gResponseData, RSPONSE_LENGTH);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not prototype the function signature if code needs to allow incompatible functions.

The following compiles without warnings/errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

ssize_t file_read(int h, const void* b, int sz) {
  if (b) return 0;
  return h + sz;
}

ssize_t file_write(int h, void* b, int sz) {
  if (b) return 0;
  return h + sz;
}

//typedef ssize_t (*genericStreamHandler)(int, void*, int);
//                                      v--- No function prototype
typedef ssize_t (*genericStreamHandler)();

int main(void) {
  genericStreamHandler gFH1 = file_read;
  genericStreamHandler gFH2 = file_write;
  char buf[10];
  return (*gFH1)(0, buf, 10) + (*gFH2)(0, buf, 10);
}
```

OTOH, the better answer may lie in taking another approach that does not need a common type for variant function signatures.